# Socket.IO crashes in IOS

Tags: ios, sockets, heroku, redis, socket.io

I have problems with Socket.IO configurations of my system. Server is on Heroku, using Redis. Configuration is:

```
var rtg = require("url").parse(url);

var pub = redis.createClient(rtg.port, rtg.hostname);
var sub = redis.createClient(rtg.port, rtg.hostname, { return_buffers: true });
pub.auth(rtg.auth.split(":")[1]);
sub.auth(rtg.auth.split(":")[1]);

var redisOptions = {
    pubClient: pub,
    subClient: sub,
    host: rtg.hostname,
    port: rtg.port
};

io.adapter(ioredis(redisOptions));
```

But I am getting the logs below from IOS client:

```
2016-04-08 11:45:52.371 xxx[2952:841559] LOG SocketEngine: Starting engine
2016-04-08 11:45:52.371 xxx[2952:841559] LOG SocketEngine: Handshaking
2016-04-08 11:45:52.372 xxx[2952:841559] LOG SocketEnginePolling: Doing polling request
2016-04-08 11:45:53.215 xxx[2952:842326] LOG SocketEnginePolling: Got polling response
2016-04-08 11:45:53.227 xxx[2952:842204] LOG SocketEngine: Got message: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style type="text/css">
    html, body, iframe { margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%; }
    iframe { display: block; width: 100%; border: none; }
  </style>
<title>Application Error</title>
</head>
<body>
  <iframe src="//s3.amazonaws.com/heroku_pages/error.html">
    <p>Application Error</p>
  </iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

And sometimes, Chrome logs the response below:

```
{"code":1,"message":"Session ID unknown"}
```

What is wrong with that configuration?